# Symfony 1.4: How to change a submit input button into an HTML link

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Seems like a simple thing, but I'm having a hell of time doing it.

I'm sure it's a quick fix... any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
<!-- apps/frontend/modules/job/templates/_form.php -->
<?php use_stylesheets_for_form($form) ?>
<?php use_javascripts_for_form($form) ?>

<?php echo form_tag_for($form, '@job') ?>
  <table id="job_form">
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="submit" value="Preview your job" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <?php echo $form ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Yes, this is straight from the JObeet tutorial... found here: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/10

With all the helpers, I thought this may be a symfony issue.  Apparently not?  At any rate, there is no action attributed to this post input method, so I can't use link_to or url_for helpers.

Comment: Can you please show the corresponding code in your template. To answer your question correctly, you need to know how you create your submit input button.

Comment: Nothing to do with symfony....

Comment: So instead of having a button (ie `<input type="submit">`) you want a link (ie `<a href=blah blah>`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly update your `form_tag_for` function call to include some attributes and give the form an id :

```
<?php echo form_tag_for($form, '@job', array('id' => 'the_form')) ?>
```

Then replace your submit button with something like this :

```
<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('the_form').submit(); return false;">Submit</a>
```

As @domi27 suggested - The symfony way - ie using helpers is the following :

```
<?php echo link_to_function('Submit', "document.getElementById('the_form').submit()") ?>
```

Comment: Genius!  Thank you so much!  I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure that out.

Comment: You may also give the `link_to_function()` helper a try !